# Bi-directional dictionary in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

Suppose I have key-value pairs having one to one mapping.
For each key I have unique value.
Then can I make a bi-directional dictionary or something similar to it which can give me value from key and vice versa?

P.S. - I know that I can use `[NSDictionary allKeysForObject: (nonnull id)]` which returns an `NSArray` of all keys having that value.

I was just wondering if there is something like bi-directional dictionary then it will be useful.

If there is something like that then please provide solution for swift also.

Thanks.

Comment: You could just maintain two dictionaries, one to map K->V and a second to map V->K. If a "bi-directional" dictionary existed (which is doesn't), it would have to do the same amount of work as two dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `Dictionary` constraining its `Value` to `Equatable` and provide your own `subscript` to return the first key for value:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    subscript(firstKeyFor value: Value) -> Key?  { first { $0.value == value }?.key }
    func allKeys(for value: Value) -> [Key] { compactMap { $0.value == value ? $0.key : nil } }
}
```

---

```
let dict = ["One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Um": 1, "Dois": 2, "Tres": 3]

if let key =  dict[firstKeyFor: 1] {
    print(key)   // "One"
}

let allKeys = dict.allKeys(for: 2)  // ["Dois", "Two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if each Key has a unique(!!!) value you can add a Category to NSDictionary with

```
-(NSString*)keyForValue:(id)value{
    NSArray* allKeys = [self allKeysForObject:value];
    return [allKeys count] > 0 ? [allKeys objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
}
```

Comment: And crash the app if there are no keys for the given value :)

Comment: Still crashes. Check the documentation for `allKeysForObject` to find out why.

Comment: ... and prefix that method with something, please.