# Does Swift 5 have a built-in Bidirectional Map?

Tags: swift, types

Does Swift 5 have a built-in data type (placeholder BidirectionalMap) that allows one to declare a constant `myBidirectionalMap` as follows:

```
let myBidirectionalMap: BidirectionalMap = [
   "foo_1":"bar_1",
   "foo_2":"bar_2",
   "foo_3":"bar_3"
]
```

where `myBidirectionalMap["foo_1"] == "bar_1"` is true, and `myBidirectionalMap["bar_1"] == "foo_1"` is also true even though it wasn't explicitly defined?

An alternative would be this:

```
let myDictionary: Dictionary = [
   "foo_1":"bar_1",
   "foo_2":"bar_2",
   "foo_3":"bar_3",
   "bar_1":"foo_1",
   "bar_2":"foo_2",
   "bar_3":"foo_3"
]
```

.

In short, I am wondering if there is a bidirectional map or equivalent in Swift 5 such that `myBidirectionalMap[key] == value` and `myBidirectionalMap[value] == key` for all keys and for all values.

As far as I have found on developer.apple.com (now that I know the correct term thanks to comments) there doesn't appear to be any built-in data type.

Comment: if it helps, what you are looking for is sometimes called BiMap, short for bidirectional map.

Comment: I don't believe there's one built-in either (or at least haven't found one yet).  You could build yourself similar functionality by extending Dictionary per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821215/bi-directional-dictionary-in-objective-c), though.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/CanTheAlmighty/70b3bf66eb1f2a5cee28

Comment: no built in, but 3rd party open source: https://github.com/schmittsfn/BiDictionary